# NetBeans 8.2 and Git: How to exclude from ignore files or directories. Vendor directory ignored by default

Tags: git, netbeans-8

I have Netbeans 8.2 and as you can see I have two files ignored correctly in my project, these files are ".gitkeep" and "app.properties". But I want to exclude from ignore all the files that are under /vendor/Demo/librery/File directory, but I have to do something wront because I don't see their changes.

[image]

**.gitignore file:**

```
.vagrant/
vendor/*
vendor/bin/*
vendor/composer/*
vendor/container-interop/*
vendor/psr/*
vendor/zendframework/*
vendor/zfcampus/*
!vendor/Demo/*
config/development.config.php
data/cache/*
data/logs/*
!data/cache/.gitkeep
phpunit.xml
ubuntu-xenial-16.04-cloudimg-console.log
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit 1:**

I have made some changes in my .gitignore file and it doesn't work.

**.gitignore file:**

```
.vagrant/
vendor/bin/*
vendor/composer/*
vendor/container-interop/*
vendor/psr/*
vendor/zendframework/*
vendor/zfcampus/*
!vendor/Demo/*
config/development.config.php
data/cache/*
data/logs/*
!data/cache/.gitkeep
phpunit.xml
ubuntu-xenial-16.04-cloudimg-console.log
```

**Edit 2:**

More changes and it doesn't work.

```
.vagrant/
!vendor/
vendor/bin/*
vendor/composer/*
vendor/container-interop/*
vendor/psr/*
vendor/zendframework/*
vendor/zfcampus/*
!vendor/Demo/*
config/development.config.php
data/cache/*
data/logs/*
!data/cache/.gitkeep
phpunit.xml
ubuntu-xenial-16.04-cloudimg-console.log
```

**Edit 3:**

Why vendor is ignored?

```
.vagrant/
#!vendor/
#vendor/bin/*
#vendor/composer/*
#vendor/container-interop/*
#vendor/psr/*
#vendor/zendframework/*
#vendor/zfcampus/*
#!vendor/Demo/*
config/development.config.php
data/cache/*
data/logs/*
!data/cache/.gitkeep
phpunit.xml
ubuntu-xenial-16.04-cloudimg-console.log
```

[image]

**Fixed it!!!**

All the solutions given to me are right. The problem with NetBeans is that you have to close NetBeans, clean the cache folder of NetBeans and finally, open again NetBeans to see the changes previously made them in .gitignore file.

Comment: Take the ! out from before the line. app.properties isn't even listed.

Comment: Doesn't work. I want to exclude from ignor /vendor/Demo/*. If I take out "!" I'm not ignoring, don't you?

Comment: Git ignores everything listed in the .gitignore file. Check the documentation here: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore  Also make sure the file is named .gitignore, not .ignore

Comment: Never mind, I see what you're trying to do now. However, according to the documentation, " It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded. "

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand how I can exclude from ignore the file ".gitkeep" and I cannot exclude from ignore everything under vendor/Demo directory :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.gitignore exclude folder but include specific subfolder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder)

Comment: As you will be aware, chatty material is discouraged here. In particular, please do not make suicide threats, even in jest - that's not really something to joke about. Keep the material focussed on the technical aspects please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I want to exclude from ignore all the files that are under `/vendor/Demo/library/File` directory,

Fist ignore vendor content, not vendor itself (the folder).
That is because: [**It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/6309)

```
/vendor/*
```

No need for all the other `vendor/xxx` rules here.

Then exclude the folders for that ignore rule:

```
!/vendor/**/
```

Finally, exclude the files you want:

```
!/vendor/Demo/library/File/**
```

Answer (score 2):

you should turn off "Ignore `vendor` folder from versioning" here

[image]

and "Permanently ignore non-sharable" here

[image]